# Excel: Lookup concatenated value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Does anyone know why the following returns #N/A?

```
=LOOKUP(TEXT(CONCATENATE($I$8,$I$5,"1"),0), CritCodes, Criteria)
```

I5 and I8 contain the following formulae and are correctly evaluating to the number 4 and R respectively:

```
=LOOKUP(B37, LevelsRange,LowLevel)
=LEFT(B29,1)
```

So the problem formula is correctly being evaluated to this, but it won't find the result.

```
=LOOKUP("R41", CritCodes, Criteria)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment - try using this formula

`=INDEX(criteria,MATCH($I$8&$I$5&1,Critcodes,0))`

`LOOKUP` isn't normally appropriate for lookups unless the lookup range is sorted ascending.....and you might want a "nearest match". `INDEX/MATCH` as used here doesn't require any sorting but also only gives an exact match, so if the lookup value doesn't exist in Critcodes you get `#N/A`

Note that in your example if I8 = "R" and I5 = 4 then `$I$8&$I$5&1` = "R41" - obviously thats a text value but that will also be the case if I8 and I5 were both numbers, so ideally Critcodes should all be text values (to do that precede any number with ' like '41)

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to lookup the string "41" rather than the integer 41. Change the formula to this:

=LOOKUP(INT(CONCATENATE($I$5,"1")), Writing, Criteria)

Comment: Yeah, when I changed the fields to text it worked.  Now I have a stranger problem along the same lines - I'll update the question.

Comment: Do you need to use the Lookup function? Could VLookup be used instead (are the CritCodes and Criteria ranges adjacent / on the same rows?) I've had issues using Lookup where it returns an approximate match rather than the one I need... there are a few things to do to make it work e.g. you need to make sure the Lookup_Vector is sorted.

Comment: Exactly right MattCrum - VLOOKUP is an option but given two distinct named ranges as here you can use this - `=INDEX(criteria,MATCH("R41",Critcodes,0))` - that will only give an exact match (or #N/A if no exact match) and nothing needs to be sorted

Comment: @barryhoudini That's fixed it - you're a star!  Please put it as an answer!